# Perl: How to match specific character in a string?

Tags: regex, perl, match

I have two files, File1 and File2. I would like to compare lines between these two files and print. However I do not find a way to match specific string. I tried the coding below, but it prints out unexpected result.
I would like to print File2 data (eg. b05**ldt**10ud0e0) when it matches to File1's names(eg. **ldt**). For those data with asterisk * in File1 (eg. b05can03*n0b5), * could be any character. For matching, It must match head and tail of an * in File2.Thus, it will print out b05can03un0b5. And printing must be follow the sequence of File1. Could anyone give me advice on this?

### File1

ldt
b05dcc00
mny
b05can03*n0b5
b05mdd04*n9c9

### File2

```
/* To start: b05afn10ud0b0 */  
/* To start: b05dcc00ud0c0 */  
/* To start: b05ldt10ud0e0 */  
/* To start: b05dcc10ud0i0 */  
/* To start: b05afn10ud0m0 */  
/* To start: b05afn10ud0s0 */  
/* To start: b05mny00ud0b5 */  
/* To start: b05mny00ud0d3 */  
/* To start: b05mdd04un9c9 */  
/* To start: b05ahn00ud0j5 */  
/* To start: b05mny00ud0m7 */  
/* To start: b05can03un0b0 */  
/* To start: b05can03un0b5 */
```

### Coding:

```
my ( @arr1, @arr2 );

@arr1 = <File1>; 
@arr2 = <File2>;

foreach my $line1 (@arr1) {
    foreach my $line2 (@arr2) {
        if ( $line1 =~ $line2 && $line1 =~ m/^\w+(\W)\w+(.*)/ ) { 
            print "$line2\n";
        }   
    }     
}
```

expected result:

b05ldt10ud0e0
b05dcc00ud0c0
b05mny00ud0b5
b05mny00ud0d3
b05mny00ud0m7
b05can03un0b5
b05mdd04un9c9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open my $File1, "<", "File1" or die $!;
open my $File2, "<", "File2" or die $!;

my @arr1 = map {
  s|\s+$||g;
  s|\*|.|g ? qr/($_)/ : qr/(\w*$_\w*)/;
}
<$File1>;

my $str = do { local $/; <$File2> };

print "$_\n" for map $str =~ /$_/g, @arr1;
```

output:

```
b05ldt10ud0e0
b05dcc00ud0c0
b05mny00ud0b5
b05mny00ud0d3
b05mny00ud0m7
b05can03un0b5
b05mdd04un9c9
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but It doesn't follow the File1 sequence. ldt...b05can3un0b5.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

my $file1 = "f1.txt";
my $file2 = "f2.txt";

open my $fh1, "<", $file1;
open my $fh2, "<", $file2;

my @wanted = map { chomp; qr/$_/; } <$fh1>;
close $fh1;

while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
    chomp $line;
    for my $wanted (@wanted) {
        say "matched: $line" if $line =~ /$wanted/;
    }   
}
close $fh2;
```

Comment: @peter, Thanks for the solution. However the result doesn't in the desired order. It should follow the File1 sequence order. And It doesn't print b05can03un0b5 and b05mdd04un9c9.

Answer (score 0):

If File2's not too large, you can slurp it into a variable, and then globally do your ordered matching on the entire string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file2 = do { local $/; local @ARGV = pop; <> };

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/\*/./g;
    print "$1\n" while $file2 =~ m!(?:/\*\s+To\s+start:\s+)(.*$_.*)(?:\s+\*/)!g;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl File1 File2`

Output:

```
b05ldt10ud0e0
b05dcc00ud0c0
b05mny00ud0b5
b05mny00ud0d3
b05mny00ud0m7
b05can03un0b5
b05mdd04un9c9
```

Hope this helps!